# How to use filtered views with ATL OLE DB

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, oledb, atl

I am developing an MFC application that accesses a mysql database. For connectivity I created a consumer class based on `CCommand` by using the ATL templates (nothing special).  Now I want to filter my data based on certain criteria. I am aware of the existence of the `IViewFilter` interface. However, I am clueless about how to implement this within the context of the templates. Searching the internet does not yield many usefull results, nor any relevant documentation by Microsoft. Any pointers in the right direction or example code would be appreciated.

Template code:

```
// Orders.h : Declaration of the COrders

#pragma once

// code generated on dinsdag 15 maart 2016, 13:11

class COrdersAccessor
{
public:
    LONG m_ID;
    TCHAR m_OrderNumber[256];
    TCHAR m_Description[256];
    LONG m_CustID;
    TCHAR m_ServiceNumber[256];
    SHORT m_Year;
    TCHAR m_directory[256];

    // The following wizard-generated data members contain status
    // values for the corresponding fields in the column map. You
    // can use these values to hold NULL values that the database
    // returns or to hold error information when the compiler returns
    // errors. See Field Status Data Members in Wizard-Generated
    // Accessors in the Visual C++ documentation for more information
    // on using these fields.
    // NOTE: You must initialize these fields before setting/inserting data!

    DBSTATUS m_dwIDStatus;
    DBSTATUS m_dwOrderNumberStatus;
    DBSTATUS m_dwDescriptionStatus;
    DBSTATUS m_dwCustIDStatus;
    DBSTATUS m_dwServiceNumberStatus;
    DBSTATUS m_dwYearStatus;
    DBSTATUS m_dwdirectoryStatus;

    // The following wizard-generated data members contain length
    // values for the corresponding fields in the column map.
    // NOTE: For variable-length columns, you must initialize these
    //       fields before setting/inserting data!

    DBLENGTH m_dwIDLength;
    DBLENGTH m_dwOrderNumberLength;
    DBLENGTH m_dwDescriptionLength;
    DBLENGTH m_dwCustIDLength;
    DBLENGTH m_dwServiceNumberLength;
    DBLENGTH m_dwYearLength;
    DBLENGTH m_dwdirectoryLength;


    void GetRowsetProperties(CDBPropSet* pPropSet)
    {
        pPropSet->AddProperty(DBPROP_CANFETCHBACKWARDS, true, DBPROPOPTIONS_OPTIONAL);
        pPropSet->AddProperty(DBPROP_CANSCROLLBACKWARDS, true, DBPROPOPTIONS_OPTIONAL);
        pPropSet->AddProperty(DBPROP_IRowsetChange, true, DBPROPOPTIONS_OPTIONAL);
        pPropSet->AddProperty(DBPROP_UPDATABILITY, DBPROPVAL_UP_CHANGE | DBPROPVAL_UP_INSERT | DBPROPVAL_UP_DELETE);
    }

    HRESULT OpenDataSource()
    {
        CDataSource _db;
        HRESULT hr;
// #error Security Issue: The connection string may contain a password
// The connection string below may contain plain text passwords and/or
// other sensitive information. Please remove the #error after reviewing
// the connection string for any security related issues. You may want to
// store the password in some other form or use a different user authentication.
        hr = _db.OpenFromInitializationString(L"Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=HCPSOrders;Extended Properties=\"DSN=HCPSOrders;\"");
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
#ifdef _DEBUG
            AtlTraceErrorRecords(hr);
#endif
            return hr;
        }
        return m_session.Open(_db);
    }

    void CloseDataSource()
    {
        m_session.Close();
    }

    operator const CSession&()
    {
        return m_session;
    }

    CSession m_session;

    DEFINE_COMMAND_EX(COrdersAccessor, L" \
    SELECT \
        ID, \
        OrderNumber, \
        Description, \
        CustID, \
        ServiceNumber, \
        Year, \
        directory \
        FROM Orders")


    // In order to fix several issues with some providers, the code below may bind
    // columns in a different order than reported by the provider

    BEGIN_COLUMN_MAP(COrdersAccessor)
        COLUMN_ENTRY_LENGTH_STATUS(1, m_ID, m_dwIDLength, m_dwIDStatus)
        COLUMN_ENTRY_LENGTH_STATUS(2, m_OrderNumber, m_dwOrderNumberLength, m_dwOrderNumberStatus)
        COLUMN_ENTRY_LENGTH_STATUS(3, m_Description, m_dwDescriptionLength, m_dwDescriptionStatus)
        COLUMN_ENTRY_LENGTH_STATUS(4, m_CustID, m_dwCustIDLength, m_dwCustIDStatus)
        COLUMN_ENTRY_LENGTH_STATUS(5, m_ServiceNumber, m_dwServiceNumberLength, m_dwServiceNumberStatus)
        COLUMN_ENTRY_LENGTH_STATUS(6, m_Year, m_dwYearLength, m_dwYearStatus)
        COLUMN_ENTRY_LENGTH_STATUS(7, m_directory, m_dwdirectoryLength, m_dwdirectoryStatus)
    END_COLUMN_MAP()
};

class COrders : public CCommand<CAccessor<COrdersAccessor> >
{
public:
    HRESULT OpenAll()
    {
        HRESULT hr;
        hr = OpenDataSource();
        if (FAILED(hr))
            return hr;
        __if_exists(GetRowsetProperties)
        {
            CDBPropSet propset(DBPROPSET_ROWSET);
            __if_exists(HasBookmark)
            {
                if( HasBookmark() )
                    propset.AddProperty(DBPROP_IRowsetLocate, true);
            }
            GetRowsetProperties(&propset);
            return OpenRowset(&propset);
        }
        __if_not_exists(GetRowsetProperties)
        {
            __if_exists(HasBookmark)
            {
                if( HasBookmark() )
                {
                    CDBPropSet propset(DBPROPSET_ROWSET);
                    propset.AddProperty(DBPROP_IRowsetLocate, true);
                    return OpenRowset(&propset);
                }
            }
        }
        return OpenRowset();
    }

    HRESULT OpenRowset(DBPROPSET *pPropSet = NULL)
    {
        HRESULT hr = Open(m_session, NULL, pPropSet);
#ifdef _DEBUG
        if(FAILED(hr))
            AtlTraceErrorRecords(hr);
#endif
        return hr;
    }

    void CloseAll()
    {
        Close();
        ReleaseCommand();
        CloseDataSource();
    }
};
```